# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {C1F400A0-3F08-11D3-9F0B-006008039E37} failed due to the following error: 80040154

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am building an application in C# using visual studio 2010 on windows server 2008, the application is to use directshownet the .net wrapper of direct show to access the system's web camera to get the video stream but the application is generating this error

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {C1F400A0-3F08-11D3-9F0B-006008039E37} failed due to the following error: 80040154.
```

the source code is below

```
  public Capture(int iDeviceNum, int iWidth, int iHeight, short iBPP, Control hControl)
    {
        DsDevice[] capDevices;
        // Get the collection of video devices
        capDevices = DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        if (iDeviceNum + 1 > capDevices.Length)
        {
            throw new Exception("No video capture devices found at that index!");
        }
        try
        {

            // Set up the capture graph
            SetupGraph(capDevices[iDeviceNum], iWidth, iHeight, iBPP);
            //// tell the callback to ignore new images
            m_PictureReady = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        }
        catch
        {
            Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }
```

the code throws the error whenever it reaches this line

```
SetupGraph(capDevices[iDeviceNum], iWidth, iHeight, iBPP);
```

please people help me out, I have googled it but couldnt find a solution

Comment: Hi,

The COM error you are getting is a "Class Not Registered" error. This could have many causes tbh; but a few of the common ones are:
- The COM Object is really not registered and therefore cannot be created
- The COM object has other dependencies which are not available.
- Mixing 64 and 32 bit requirements (.Net 64 bit, with 32 bit COM components).

Comment: thanks, I have been able to solve the problem, its like the directshow.net requires a qedit.dll which was not on my windows server, I downloaded the dll and used regsvr32 to register and I stopped recieving the error

Answer (score 1):

That guid is associated with a capture device with the name ["Sample Grabber"](http://www.myplugins.info/guids/component_programming.php?guid=C1).  It is declared in an SDK header named qedit.h, docs [are here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Note the deprecation warning, qedit.h is no longer part of the Windows SDK and I don't have it installed on my Windows 7 machine.

It sounds like you have a slight case of registry corruption, possibly induced by a Windows upgrade.  With the Sample Grabber filter still enlisted as a device but the actual filter no longer registered.  No idea how to fix this damage, ask at superuser.com.  These kind of mishaps are however likely to occur on your user's machine as well.  Do catch the exception and continue looking for another available capture device.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to compile your project explicitly in x86 mode instead of Any and see if that fixes the issue. It's also possible you are missing a required DLL on your machine.

Comment: the compilation is in x86 mode and it still gives the same error